# Android AppWidget PendingIntent Activity Transition Animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-animation, android-pendingintent

I am trying to control the activity transition animation when the user taps a home widget with a pending intent to start an activity that is **not** the launcher activity.

This is the tap intent:

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        /* context = */ this,
        /* requestCode = */  0,
        /* intent = */ Intent(this, ActivityEdit::class.java),
        /* flags = */ PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
```

When trying the usual methods, for example:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout)
```

right after `finish()`, it is still showing the default system animation of sliding down the activity.

From documentation:

> Af of Build.VERSION_CODES.S application can only specify a transition
> animation when the transition happens within the same task. System
> default animation is used for cross-task transition animations.

When I try to start the launcher activity, the system default animation is more than acceptable, but another type of activity starts fine with fade in, but finished with sliding down, which I wanted to change to fade out.

My app's min SDK is 31.
Does that mean there is no way of controlling the activity transition animation that starts from a home widget tap?